# Building issues with Spatialite

Tags: c++, sqlite, ubuntu, gis, spatialite

I'm trying to build Spatialite 4.1.1 in Ubuntu 12.04. I'm getting the following build errors while building.

virtualXL.c: In function 'vXL_create':
virtualXL.c:264:3: error: unknown type name 'FreeXL_CellValue'
virtualXL.c:265:3: warning: passing argument 4 of 'freexl_get_cell_value' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/freexl.h:202:24: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'int *'
virtualXL.c:265:3: error: too few arguments to function 'freexl_get_cell_value'
/usr/include/freexl.h:202:24: note: declared here
virtualXL.c:270:17: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:271:39: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:272:22: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:275:17: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:276:22: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:277:18: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:278:18: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:279:18: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:280:18: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:282:30: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:286:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c: In function 'vXL_eval_constraints':
virtualXL.c:505:5: error: unknown type name 'FreeXL_CellValue'
virtualXL.c:551:10: warning: passing argument 4 of 'freexl_get_cell_value' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/freexl.h:202:24: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'int *'
virtualXL.c:551:10: error: too few arguments to function 'freexl_get_cell_value'
/usr/include/freexl.h:202:24: note: declared here
virtualXL.c:553:12: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:554:12: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:561:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:565:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:569:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:573:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:577:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:587:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:591:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:595:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:599:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:603:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:609:12: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:616:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:620:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:624:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:628:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:632:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:642:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:646:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:650:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:654:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:658:16: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:664:13: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:665:16: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:666:16: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:667:16: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:668:16: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:670:13: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c: In function 'vXL_column':
virtualXL.c:804:5: error: unknown type name 'FreeXL_CellValue'
virtualXL.c:819:11: warning: passing argument 4 of 'freexl_get_cell_value' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/freexl.h:202:24: note: expected 'unsigned char *' but argument is of type 'int *'
virtualXL.c:819:11: error: too few arguments to function 'freexl_get_cell_value'
/usr/include/freexl.h:202:24: note: declared here
virtualXL.c:821:6: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:822:17: error: request for member 'type' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:825:38: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:828:41: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:835:39: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union
virtualXL.c:836:23: error: request for member 'value' in something not a structure or union

It looks like a version problem with libfreeXL. Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you have to edit your **config.h** and change the line

```
#undef OMIT_FREEXL
```

with

```
#define OMIT_FREEXL
```

...But, if you *need* to extract data from Excel files, [download FreeXL here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/freexl/index):